# ¿Cómo ocultar el botón eliminar con eliminación lógica en el Django admin?

Tags: python, django

Necesito ocultar el botón eliminar cuando estoy en la vista del detalle de un objeto en el Django admin.

Estoy usando eliminación lógica de modelos y parra ello sobreescribo el método `delete_model`:

```
def delete_model(self, request, obj):
    obj.eliminado_el = timezone.now()
    obj.eliminado = True
    obj.save()
```

Entonces cuando `obj.eliminado` sea `True` se debe ocualtar el botón eliminar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Lo que quieres hacer es relativamente sencillo, para lograrlo basta con sobreescribir el método [`ModelAdmin.has_delete_permission`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_delete_permission):

```
class MiModeloAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj and obj.eliminado:
            return False
        return True
```

Esta función indica si se tiene o no permisos para eliminar el objeto, entonces, solo tendrías que validar si el objeto ha sido borrado lógicamente y retornar `False` en esos casos.

Si quisieras quitar la opción para eliminar los objetos en el listado del modelo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Puedes hacerlo sobreescribiendo el método [`ModelAdmin.get_actions`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_actions):

```
class MiModeloAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    def get_actions(self, request):
        actions = super(MiModeloAdmin, self).get_actions(request)
        if 'delete_selected' in actions:
            del actions['delete_selected']
        return actions
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @César

Comment: Efectivamente, esa es la respuesta, en la documentación hallas el tema de permisos, con el puedes quitar privilegios a ciertos usuarios, la manera más fácil es a través de grupos, creas un grupo y dentro de tú código lo referencias para según sus permisos otorgar o quitar privilegios.